# Apache URL Rewriting Causing Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Why does the following Apache configuration produce an internal server error:

```
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "page/" and "page" to "page.php" . Also, redirect "page/en/" and "page/en" to "page.php?lang=en" .
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?([a-z]?)/?$ $1.php?lang=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

So, basically, all I'm trying to do is add ".php" onto the end of the page, and if a "/en" part exists, then add it as the language parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason why your rule is failing:** Your Rewrite rule is causing infinite looping and Apache is throwing internal server error (500) because `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` (default).

Here is how you should write Rewrite rule for this task:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MySite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:/(.*?)/?)?$ $1.php?lang=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I've just tried this and I'm getting "Object not found!" when I try all these URLs: http://127.0.0.1/MySite/about/en/, http://127.0.0.1/MySite/about/en, http://127.0.0.1/MySite/about/ and http://127.0.0.1/MySite/about . I should be getting served the file at http://127.0.0.1/MySite/about.php . NB - the .htaccess file is located the MySite directory.

Comment: Ah you didn't mention about MySite in your question. I will edit my answer now.